# File encoding altered by FTP transfer

Tags: ftp, encoding

A user has used FTP to transfer some HTML files to our webserver. These HTML files contain characters such as:

```
‘ ’
```

which aren't properly encoded in HTML markup. When they've been uploaded, the website displays the � character (which can sometimes happen), but even if I open the HTML file in gedit directly on the server, the same encoding problem is there.

Any ideas on why this would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to set your transfer mode to "binary"

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the different FTP transfer modes.